# How i can read/write file on internal storage?

Tags: android

I am working on a project for JSON Parse on local file.
It is working as well on Android Studio emulator, but doesn't work on my own Phone.
Problem is file path and i can not change this path to internal storage from external storage.

[MY CLASS FILE (for read a file)]

```
class fetchData extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEST.json");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            String data = null;
            try {
                FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
                data = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                stream.close();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray Data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.length(); i++) {
                Urun urun = new Urun();
                //(CENSORED)
                uruns.add(urun);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), uruns);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

[MY CLASS FILE (for write a file)]

```
class fetchDataWrite extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEST.json");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            String data = null;
            try {
                FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
                data = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                stream.close();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray Data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
            //(CENSORED)
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(yourFile);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(/*CENSORED STRING*/);
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[MY APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Dz9.jpg) showing data on TEST.json file like this.

- Path on Android Studio Emulator(AndroidV:5.1.1): (/storage/sdcard/TEST.json) -it is working.
- Path on my Phone(AndroidV:11): : (/storage/emulated/0/TEST.json) -it doesn't working.

  How i can fix this? Can it work on my phone?

```
File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEST.json");
```

I tried add spesific folder and I moved this file to "Download" Folder. It is worked as well on Emulator but didn't work on my phone.

```
File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/TEST.json");
```

My Question is : How i can change this "file path" on java.class for my app work on My Phone?

Comment: This is on an Android 10 device? Or on an Android 11+ device?

Comment: @blackapps I added Android versions of Devices to my Question. -My Phone's Android version is 11.

Comment: On an Android 11+ device your app cannot create files on /storage/emulated/0/ but it can in /storage/emulated/0/Download when it has the usual WRITE permission.

Comment: Your app is trying to READ a file? A file it did not create itself? That will not go on an Android 11+ device. Unless some media files in special directories.

Comment: @blackapps My app is need to Read and Write this file and It is doing this well on Emulator.

Comment: @blackapps Can i fixed this for work on Device on Android verison is 11? But its need to Read and Write a file like this(Like now on Android 5.1 Emulator)

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: @blackapps if my android device version is 9, How i can fix the path? Current path is looking SDCARD only maybe.

Comment: @blackapps can i change the path for go to internal storage? DCIM, Documents or Download folders etc, i mean main storage do u understand me ?

Comment: You did not answer my questions or remarks. Its time you do.

Comment: @blackapps im working on it. But i found a alternative solution for android versions up to 11.

Answer (score 0):

I found a alternative solution on android versions up to 11. Now i can reach the /storage/emulated/0/test.json or i can reach the other folders like DCIM, Download, etc.

add this lines to AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

...and **request this permission** from user using app. This solved my Questions very well. But you guys need to be carefully when using this permission. (if you will publish your app google play)

[How to Request?](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)
(If you will try this without ask permission, you can do it manually [From here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcv0u.jpg))